# Java Jtree mouseEvent if nothing is selected

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jtree

I am trying to figure out how to code a event that, if clicked in a Swing JTree and the mouse does not click anything in the tree, to get a println that says "nothing".

Say I have a tree 'info_tree' with an AWT.event.Mouwesvent as such:

```
private void info_treeMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {   
    if(info_tree.getSelectionPath() /*something along the lines of is empty or if !info_tree.getSelectionPath().isEmpty()*/
       ){system.out.println("Nothing");
      }else{
          system.out.println("Something");
      }
}
```

I can't find anything to compare a selectedPath or element of a tree.

Comment: *"I am trying to figure out how to code a event that, if clicked in a Swing JTree and the mouse does not click anything in the tree, to get a println that says "nothing"."*  .. why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may wish to try

```
If (info_tree.getSelectionPath()==null)
```

But,then you may want to switch your output lines around. Because that as-is is a true/false condition. If false it'll goto else. That could solve it as well.

Comment: This did solve it. The problem was that if i was clicking in the JTree panel and I was not selecting anything, I would get a NullPointerException (makes sense of course).
What also fixes the problem is Adding a default selecter to the tree.
`info_tree.setSelectionRow(0);`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this program:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class JTreeGetSelectedNode extends JFrame {
    public JTreeGetSelectedNode() throws HeadlessException {
        initializeUI();
    }

    private void initializeUI() {
        setSize(200, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Countries");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode asia = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Asia");
        String[] countries = new String[] {"India", "Singapore", "Indonesia", "Vietnam"};
        for (String country : countries) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(country);
            asia.add(node);
        }

        DefaultMutableTreeNode northAmerica = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("North America");
        countries = new String[] {"United States", "Canada"};
        for (String country : countries) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(country);
            northAmerica.add(node);
        }

        DefaultMutableTreeNode southAmerica = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("South America");
        countries = new String[] {"Brazil", "Argetina", "Uruguay"};
        for (String country : countries) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(country);
            southAmerica.add(node);
        }

        DefaultMutableTreeNode europe = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Europe");
        countries = new String[] {"United Kingdom", "Germany", "Spain", "France", "Italy"};
        for (String country : countries) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(country);
            europe.add(node);
        }

        root.add(asia);
        root.add(northAmerica);
        root.add(southAmerica);
        root.add(europe);

        final JTree tree = new JTree(root);
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(tree);
        pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 400));


        JButton button = new JButton("Get Selected");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Object paths = tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent();

      if(paths == null){
      System.out.println("nothig");
      }else{
      System.out.println("Something");
      }
            }
        });

        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        getContentPane().add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new JTreeGetSelectedNode().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be partly anwering the question. This way, you eliminate the problem of clicking whilst nithing is selected. So taking away the problem of clicking by replacing it. This is also a way to fix the problem. Thouth in my opinion it is only adding unnecessary code.

Comment: you take the code inside button. i think, would be fine.

Comment: The point is, if there is nothing selected from the tree, you will get a `NullPointerException` because there is no `LastSelectedPathComponent`.